# Record Video in React App and Upload to Dropbox

Tags: reactjs, dropbox, video-capture, mediarecorder

This seemed like a pretty straightforward ask for a freelance gig I'm doing, but for one reason or another I'm having trouble recording a video (using built in hardware) and uploading it as a file (mp4) using the Dropbox API. I've been back and forth with this and another project and am a newer developer, so I feel like it's something silly that I'm missing, but have not been able to figure it out yet. Any help would be HUGE! Here is the file I'm having trouble with. I'm using the react-media-recorder library.

```
const UploadView = () => {
  const {
    startRecording,
    stopRecording,
    mediaBlobUrl,
  } = useReactMediaRecorder({ video: true, audio: true, blobPropertyBag: {
    type: "video/mp4"
} });

  const [curStatus, setCurStatus] = useState(true);
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();
  const [isFilePicked, setIsFilePicked] = useState(false);

  // Handles upload of selected file to Dropbox
  const uploadToDropbox = () => {
    // const UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE_LIMIT = 150 * 1024 * 1024;
    console.log('Selected File:', selectedFile);
    var ACCESS_TOKEN = process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN;
    var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN });
    console.log('FILE:', selectedFile);
        dbx.filesUpload({path: '/' + selectedFile.name, contents: selectedFile})
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error(error);
        });
    
    }

    // Starts recording of new video
    const startedRec = () => {
      startRecording();
      setCurStatus(false);
    }

    // Stops recording of new video and creates blob
    const stoppedRec = async () => {
      stopRecording();
      setCurStatus(true);
      const videoBlob = await fetch(mediaBlobUrl).then(r => r.blob());
      const url = new Blob ([videoBlob]);
      // Creates a video file with a randomized file name
      const videoFile = new File([videoBlob], `${uuidv4()}.${"mp4"}`, { type: "video/mp4" })

      console.log('Video File:', videoFile);
      console.log('Blob:', url);
        
      
      setSelectedFile(videoFile);
      setIsFilePicked(true);
    }

    // Handles input change and assigns input value to selectedFile variable
    const changeHandler = (event) => {
      setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
      setIsFilePicked(true);
    };
  

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={Logo} className="logo"></img>
      {!isFilePicked ?
      <div className='player-wrapper'>
        <img src={Photo}/>
      </div> :
      <video width="700" height="350" controls>
        <source src={URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile)}/>
      </video>
      }
      <h1
        className="icon"
      >
        <img src={Icon}/>
      </h1>
      {curStatus ?
      <span>     
        <label
          className="video-record" 
          for="video-record">
            RECORD VIDEO
        </label>
        <input 
          id="video-record"
          onClick={startedRec}
        />
      </span>  
      :
      <span>     
        <label
          className="video-record" 
          for="video-record">
            STOP RECORDING
        </label>
        <input 
          id="video-record"
          onClick={stoppedRec}
        />
      </span>  
      }
      {!isFilePicked ?
      <span>
        <label 
          className="file-upload"
          for="file-upload">
            UPLOAD VIDEO
        </label>
        <input 
          id="file-upload"
          type="file"
          onChange={changeHandler}
        /> 
      </span> :
      <span>
        <label 
          className="file-upload"
          for="confirm-upload">
            SUBMIT VIDEO
        </label>
        <input 
          id="confirm-upload"
          type="submit"
          onClick={() => uploadToDropbox()}
        /> 
      </span>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadView;
```

The file ends up being created and uploaded to dropbox, but it's shown as if it's an empty file. Regardless of the length of the recording, it shows up as the same file size, so I'm not sure what I'm missing. Please let me know if anyone sees something I'm missing at first glance!